# How to remove a CSS class when the Element has a specific Class in Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular8

I am using Angular `NgClass` directive to change the color of my title and it is working as expected:

`[ngClass]="{ 'text-warning':progress == '1', 'text-success':progress == '2' }`

The problem is: when the `<a>` tag has the class `active` I want to **remove** the previously added class for my title.

```
<div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
  <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
      <div class="col-md-7"><strong>{{module.title}}</strong></div>
      <div class="col-md-5" style="text-align: end;">
        <small
          [ngClass]="{ 'text-warning':progress == '1', 'text-success':progress == '2' }"
        >
          - {{getProgress(module.moduleProgress)}}
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `ngClass` with `<a>` to add / remove `active` class, and use the same condition with your other `ngClass`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava the active class with the `<a>` is added and removed by the bootstrap script automatically, you suggest that i do it manually to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue using some custom CSS classes instead of the bootstrap one's:

First I've added these classes:

```
.active small{
    color: white !important;
}

.text-green {
    color:green;
}

.text-orange {
    color: orange;
}
```

and then replace `text-warning` and `text-success` respectively by the previously added classes "text-green" and "text-orange".

**NOTE:** the problem was that bootstrap text coloring classes all use `!important`, removing it from the custom classes did the trick.